# My chest voice range is extremely narrow,

Tags: voice, vocal-range

I'm a male singer. I've been studying voice, training, and doing exercises for almost 15 years and my natural chest voice range is still about the same, a D3 to about an F4. It's always been this way. I've been able to sing more easily and comfortably in head voice. I get above F4 in chest then I have to push really hard, which I'm always told sounds strained. Because of this the training I've done I've learned to start mixing at around E4 to F4, but it's so light that it basically might as well be head voice once I get up to G4, and there's no real power behind it.

It's really frustrating because I don't have the ability to sing lower notes, nor do I have the resonance of a baritone, but I can't hit high notes comfortable the way natural tenors do. This to me just doesn't seem normal or natural and I am wondering if I have something wrong with my voice.

Comment: I could have thought I've read posts and/or comments on this website saying that the average person's singing range is more than an octave but considerably less than 2 - rather like your chest voice range.

Comment: Hey, on the bright side: people's voices do usually tend to become different with age, especially men, all throughout their lives. So there may still be hope yet for a change, if you're unhappy with what you've got at the moment!

Comment: There are probably more people in the world who have the limitations you describe, than those without. We are what we are, too often! Use what you've been given, tailor the keys to what you can use productively, and be glad that you can at least sing in tune.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to *push hard*, you're singing wrong and you can damage your voice. I also noted you said you starting mixing around E4 to F4.  I can tell you, as a second bass, that if you start in chest voice, it's extremely hard, if not impossible, to switch into mix that way. I was taught to start in mix and remain in mix so that when I switch to head voice, it's easier and there's no forceful singing involved.

You also mention that your mix is so light it may as well be "head voice".  I'm wondering if you're actually not using mix, but falsetto.  They're not the same. Head voice has volume control with it, falsetto has absolutely no volume control, it's soft only.
For example, Leo Sayer sings "Sad Eyes" almost exclusively in head voice, Frankie Valie sings "Sherry" and a lot of his other songs in head voice as well.
The backup vocalist in Air Supply (not Russell Hitchcock) always sings in falsetto, his voice is always airy and soft.

It makes me wonder if you're really singing where you think your singing. I also note that you said you've been studying voice, but you never said if it's on your own or with a teacher. If you're studying on your own, it would be best to study with a teacher. There are teachers who will give Skype lessons  (Brett Manning is well known for doing this - and his voice teacher was Seth Riggs, who's also pretty well known himself (Shameless plug - he's my voice teacher as well!! ) )

I can tell you that with voice lessons, you can both add power and range. I've done so myself. Please stop trying to force your range  higher, it wont work and it *will* damage your voice!

Comment: so you say he can actually sing trough f4-a4 comfortably of he will do the right exercises? i am having the same doubts as the questioner, but i have no experience in training with teacher

Comment: Since C4 is middle "C" , I'd say it's possible to expand your range to at  least F4. Again, I'm a second bass and can sing down to "C" 2 octaves below middle "C", however, before I started voice training I could hit middle "C" if I was lucky. Now, middle "C" (aka C4) is no sweat, with a good warm-up I can hit "G" over middle "C" with a good warm-up, in mix.   With a competent voice teacher and practice, anyone's range can be extended.

Comment: i can reach g4 on good day and f4# is possible at any moment most of the time.. is that mean that vocal training can expand my voice to reach a4 easily?